# Alternative for PHP linter

Tags: php

Basically, php -l does not detect any syntax error, given this code:

```
<?php
date®;
?>
```

Obviously, it's an error when you execute it.

Is there any alternative or additional linter to use for PHP?

EDIT:

Thanks alot guys. Apparently it *is* a valid constant name, as the documentation suggests ([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*).

Comment: Why is it an error? It's a valid constant name. It's only an error if the constant is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only errors because you haven't a constant definition for date®

If, somewhere in another script file before an include of your test file you have:

```
define('date®','Value');
```

this would be valid (albeit meaningless) and would run without error

So syntactically this file is valid, and a lint check duly reports it as such

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `php_check_syntax` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php).

Let me correct my answer. It will not detect the latter code as an error (as noted in the comments, this isn't erroneous code). Though, you should stick with the latter function if you want to check file for errors.